# es6 mix require and imports in a same project

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, import, export

I'm starting a new NodeJs / Browser project in Es6.

Is in possible to "mix" es6 modules and "legacy" requires (for nodeJs) or "legacy" script tags ( for browser) in a same project ?
I ask this because of third parties libraries that might not been written with the new ES6 "import" syntax

For the NodeJs side, I tried something like :

main file : wTestNode.mjs

```
import * as rTest from './rTest.js';
let vRqTest= new rTest.rqTest();
```

with rTest.js (in the same directory)

```
class rqTest
{
  constructor()
  { console.log('rqTest.create'); }
}

exports={rqTest};
```

but all I Have is "TypeError: rTest.rqTest is not a constructor"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
export default class rqTest
{
  constructor()
  { console.log('rqTest.create'); }

  testLog() {
    console.log('rqTest.test');
  }
}
```

And to use this class:

```
import rqTest from './rTest.js'
let vRqTest= new rTest();
vRqTest.testLog();
```

Comment: I tested but I have an "Unexpected token 'export'" error in rTest.js